# Failed to connect to xxxxx port 82: Connection refused

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I setup https://github.com/Athlon1600/php-proxy script :

my config.php file like this :

```
// additional curl options to go with each request
$config['curl'] = array(
  CURLOPT_PROXY => "xxxx.ir:82",
  CURLOPT_HEADER => False ,
  CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS => False ,
  CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => "uuuu:ppppppp" ,
  CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL => 1 ,
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5
);
```

**but I get error**

> Failed to connect to xxxxx port 82: Connection refused

Comment: So there's no proxy on that host listening on TCP port 82.

Comment: Or some kind of firewall active?

Comment: when i request url without ip-port , It work very well . it dosn't work with ip-port

Comment: also i don't use it on local , i  upload php-proxy on my web site